# Facebook sharer link error

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress

I am using a plugin in my wordpress site. The plugin is called videolock and the user have to share a video in his/her facebook profile in order to see it. The plugin works great apart from one part. The sharer link that is open when the user clicks the share button doesn't work properly.

the sharer's url when clicking the share button is (https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/sharer/sharer.php?u=http...). When i remove the "v2.0" from the link the share window opens appropriately. What should i change in my code to make it work?

the wrong part must be somewhere here (within the locker.js of the plugin):

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var lockers = $(".youtubeblocker");

    if( lockers.length == 0  ) {
        return;
    }

    var fbid = lockers.attr('data-appid');

    if( !fbid && lockers.length ) {
        lockers.append('<div style="z-index:10000; font-size:15px; position:absolute; padding:5px; left:5px; right:5px; top:5px; text-align:center; background:red;color:white;">Please set the facebook appId from admin</div>');
        return;
    }

    lockers.each(function(i, blocker){

        $(blocker).hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('over');
        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('over');
        }).click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('sharing');                
            new CountDown($(blocker));
        });

        $('.sharebut',blocker).click( function(){

            var but = this;

            var save = function( share ) {

                var data = {
                    action : 'video_share',
                    link : document.URL,
                    post : $(but).attr('data-post'),
                    share : share
                };

                var admin_ajax = $(blocker).attr('data-adminurl') + 'admin-ajax.php';

                $.post( admin_ajax, data, function( r ){
                    unblock( $(but).parents('.youtubeblocker') );
                });
            };

            FB.ui({
                    method: isMobile() ? 'feed' : '../sharer/sharer.php?u=' +encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+ '&t=&pass=',
                    link : document.URL,
                    image : $('.youtubeblocker .image').attr('src')
                },
                function(response) {

                    if (response) {

                        var postid = 0;

                        if( response.post_id ) {
                            postid = response.post_id;
                        }

                        if( response.object_id ) {
                            postid = response.object_id;
                        }

                        save( postid );                   
                    }
                }
            );

            return false;
        });
    });

    var jssdk = $('#facebook-jssdk');

    if( ! jssdk.length ) {

        var fb = document.createElement('div');
        fb.setAttribute('id','fb-root');
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(fb);

        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + fbid;
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change like this:

```
method: isMobile() ? 'share' : '../../sharer/sharer.php?u=' +encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+ '&t=&pass='
```